# Change DataClasses in HighCharts - JQuery / JavaScript

Tags: jquery, highcharts

```
dataClasses: [
{
    from: 0,
    color: '#09ad00'
}, {
    from: chartData.lowThreshold + 1,
    color: '#DDDF0D'
}, {
    from: chartData.highThreshold,
    color: '#d00000'
}
```

]

```
$CHART_CONTAINER.highcharts(Highcharts.merge(solidGaugeOptions, {
colorAxis: {

},
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0, '', '');
        }
    },
    tickInterval: chartData.total,
    endOnTick: false,
    maxPadding: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: chartData.total,
    dataClasses: [
        {
            from: 0,
            color: '#09ad00'
        }, {
            from: chartData.lowThreshold + 1,
            color: '#DDDF0D'
        }, {
            from: chartData.highThreshold,
            color: '#d00000'
        }
    ]
},
series: [
    {
        data: [chartData.currentData],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<div class="gauge-data-label"><span class="gauge-data-number" >{y}</span><hr><small class="gauge-data-description">Doors</small></div>'
        }
    }
]
```

}));

Our end users can modify the low threshold and high threshold in basically attempt to change the color ranges of when a range is green, yellow or shows red on the chart.  I am new to HighCharts and do not how to programmaticaly change the color ranges in JQuery?

Comment: Here is the full code above

Comment: Looking at the API I don't see a direct method.  I think you will need to redefine your options, destroy the current chart, and create a new one with the updated options.

Comment: Okay Thanks! - so I think I now how to do the destroy but am unclear on how to take my above chart and create the chart again in JQuery?

Comment: colorAxis is the same as any other axis. Simply try to use `chart.colorAxis[0].update(new_options);`. However, this is a little buggy, see [this ticket](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3207).

Comment: Huh I get can not read property 0 of undefined?  When attempting chart.colorAxis[0].update(new_options);

Comment: I didn't get notification about your update. It looks like you haven't created any colorAxis on your chart. Could your show me jsFiddle with this issue? I will check this.